# Manage auto layout for imageview in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I need to give auto layout constraint for ImageView in this type of layout all other stuff are perfect but ImageView are not upto the mark.
[image]

All three boxes in image are ImageViews First from left, I tried storyboard layout Leading, Trailing, bottom and Width fix and for second imageview-> Leading, Top, Trailing and height fix. Bind their respective width and height constraint and programatically doing this:

```
imageView1WConstraint.constant = 310 * WIDTH_RATIO;
imageView2HConstraint.constant = 156 * HEIGHT_RATIO;
```

P.S: WIDTH_RATIO and HEIGHT_RATIO are macros and defined like this for iPad.

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

#define WIDTH_RATIO SCREEN_WIDTH / 768
#define HEIGHT_RATIO SCREEN_HEIGHT / 1024
```

I tried this all but imageview are different at runtime, can anyone help me in achieving this?